# Is possible to cast BehaviorSubject into an array stream?

Tags: angular, rxjs6

Is it possible to convert or cast the BehaviorSubject to an array stream? Or pls advise best practice.

#### Objective is to return the total price of groceries ###

*data.js*

```
export const ShoppingList = {
  id: 22,
  username: 'Duff',
  groceries: [
    {
      day: 'Monday',
      purchases: [ { item: 'Beer', price: 10 }, { item: 'Pizza', price: 15 } ]
    },
    {
      day: 'Tuesday',
      purchases: [ { item: 'Wine', price: 10 }, { item: 'Steak', price: 15 } ]
    },
  ]
}
```

*service.ts*

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ShoppingList } from './data.js'
//
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { pluck } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class DataService {
  shopping_list$ = new BehaviorSubject<any>(ShoppingList);

  user_name$ = this.shopping_list$.pipe(pluck('username');
  id$ = this.shopping_list$.pipe(pluck('id')

  **day$ = new BehaviorSubject<[]>(ShoppingList_groceries[0].day);**

  **purchases$ = new BehaviorSubject<[]>(ShoppingList_groceries[0].purchases);**

  constructor() {}
}
```

#### #

*list-component.ts*

```
import { DataService } from '../service/data.service.ts';
//
import { from, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { tap, map, pluck, reduce, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-list',
  templateUrl: './list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./list.component.css']
})

export class ListComponent implements OnInit {

  shopping_list = this.dataService.shopping_list$;
  user_name = this.dataService.user_name$;
  id = this.dataService.id$;
  day = this.dataService.day$

  ***prices = this.dataService.purchases$.pipe(
       pluck('prices'),
       reduce((a:number, c:number) => a + c),
       tap(y => console.log(y))
     );***


  constructor(private dataService: DataService) {}



  ngOnInit() {
    this.shopping_list.subscribe(val => console.log(val))
    this.prices.subscribe(val => console.log(val))
  }

}
```

#### > returns undefined

#### > or without pluck and reduce returns whole array [{},{}]

*list-component.html*

```
<h1>{{ user_name }} {{ id }} </h1>
<p>{{ day }}</p>
<p>{{ prices }}</p>
```

is it possible to pipe a ***BehaviorSubject*** to work like ***from** function? Is this best practice or is there a better pattern to build?
Any feedback would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**BehaviorSubject**

> A Subject that requires an initial value and emits its current value
>   to new subscribers

In other words. Think of it like a store rather than a stream of data. You put something in it and once someone subscribes to it now or later will get that value back.

Not possible to cast into an array stream.

One possible approach would be the following:

First collect and summarize all purchases by days.

```
  purchasesByDays$ = new BehaviorSubject<number[]>(
    ShoppingList.groceries.map(day => {
      return day.purchases.reduce((total, purc) => total + purc.price, 0);
    })
  );
```

Once this is done, pipe to this with a simple map in the component.

```
this.grandTotal$ = this.dataService.purchasesByDays$
  .pipe(
    map(
      (arr: number[]) => { 
        return arr.reduce((total: number, curr: number) => total + curr, 0);
    })
  );
```

Demo [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rpycn5?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdata.service.ts).

Comment: an array can easily be turned into a stream `mergeMap(arr => from(arr))` but it's over engineering in many cases and rarely needed. In this case, this is the correct answer. Treat a stream of arrays as a stream of arrays, don't force it to be a stream of streams and then force it back.

Comment: Thanks so much, Good solutions. Really, really appreciate it. : D 

Comment: @DouggyC Wonderful! Please mark this as the answer if it solved your issue :) Thank you!